# How to improve the disassembler view in IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM v7.30

Tags: assembly, arm, iar

I'm using IAR embedded workbench for ARM v7.30, and a Jlink JTAG debugger to connect to an ARM development board. I write in Assembler, not C. While much of the disassembly view in the IAR debugger for the project is correct, some of it isn't:

```
; ORIGINAL SOURCE CODE
    BL setup_starting_address
    TSTS R4, #ERR_ADDRESS_SETUP  
    BNE error_while_reading       
send_command
    MOV R3, #COMMAND_READ 
    BL  CF_send_command
    TSTS R4, #ERR_COMMAND
    BNE  error_while_reading 
wait_for_flag_to_be_set
    BL get_status
    TSTS R4, #STATUS_BIT3
    BEQ wait_for_flag_to_be_set
```

renders as this:

```
;DISASSEMBLY VIEW
        0x204: 0xf7ff 0xffc4  BL        setup_starting_address ; 0x190
EPIDMATXCNT:
        0x208: 0xf414 0x2f00  TST.W     R4, #524288             ; 0x80000
        0x20c: 0xd113         BNE.N     error_while_reading ; 0x236
send_command:
        0x20e: 0xf04f         DC16      61519                   ; 'Oð'
EPIIM:
        0x210: 0x0320         LSLS      R0, R4, #12
        0x212: 0xf7ff         DC16      63487                   ; 'ÿ÷'
EPIRIS:
        0x214: 0xff83 0xf414  VMOV.I32  D15,#0xb40000
EPIMIS:
        0x218: 0x3f00         SUBS      R7, #0
        0x21a: 0xd10c         BNE.N     error_while_reading ; 0x236
EPIEISC:
wait_for_flag_to_be_set:
        0x21c: 0xf7ff 0xff4c  BL        get_status           ; 0xb8
        0x220: 0xf014 0x0f08  TST.W     R4, #8
        0x224: 0xd0fa         BEQ.N     wait_for_flag_to_be_set  ; 0x21c
```

This example is typical of the problem. In the code shown, the debugger window is correct, except this block in the middle:

```
MOV R3, #COMMAND_READ 
BL  CF_send_command
TSTS R4, #ERR_COMMAND
```

which it renders as:

```
DC16      61519 
LSLS      R0, R4, #12
DC16      63487 
VMOV.I32  D15,#0xb40000
SUBS      R7, #0
```

I'd like to remedy this, and even better, for the package to track the single step progress in the source view like I've seen in C demonstrations. I'm assuming I'm missing something in the IAR EW setup? How do I change the setup to help the debugger to sync better to the source code, and thus provide a cleaner interpretation of it?

The settings I've been playing with are these: 
In PROJECT>OPTIONS>ASSEMBLER>OUTPUT 'Generate debug information' is ticked. 
And I've been looking round at the files it creates during build seeing if I could export extra information that would help.
In PROJECT>OPTIONS>DEBUGGER>IMAGES there are options for 'Download extra image' but information on these seems sparse and trying them with various files hasn't worked.

Searching the IDE and debugger manuals doesn't offer much either.

I am barking up the right tree?

Comment: Strange. No idea why it has a problem disassembling that piece of code. Maybe you need to force thumb mode?

Comment: It's not a question of getting the debugger in sync with your source code. It's not looking at it when it disassembles those instructions. It's looking at the actual code running on the ARM processor. The problem is that it's not disassembling the code the way you expect it to. There's a few possible reasons for this. One is that it simply doesn't know how to decode these instructions. Another is that it mistakenly believes your ARM CPU doesn't supports these instructions. Finally, it may be correct that your ARM CPU doesn't support these instructions.

Comment: @RossRidge note that it has no problem disassembling the same `BL` instructions in preceding and following blocks.

Comment: @Jester Good point. I think see the problem now. The labels `EPIIM` and `EPIRIS` are causing it to start disassembling in the middle of instructions. So it I guess its case of the debugger picking up something from the source code through the debugging info that it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Also, since the addresses are pretty low, maybe it's misinterpreting some other symbolic constants defined elsewhere as if they were code labels.

Comment: @Ross Ridge. & Jester aswell. I have just commented out the symbolic constants in the equates file that were in range of the code here, and sure enough the disassembler view of it cleans up completely. The Equates file is fairly large, and growing, and it leaves the disassembler view riddled with unwanted references. I think there maybe another issue here that effects IAR's ability to do its job - that is that the single stepping in the disassembler window works fine but it doesn't ever track in the source code window. It's like a link between them is broken.

Comment: @Jester. Do you think the symbolic constants being misinterpreted as lables is a setup problem or an IAR bug? I've tried a few things to try to fix this but none have been successful. I've seen it in other people's code when watching tutorials. When the label clutter gets so bad IAR truncates their display and puts a message like "+27 symbols not displayed" in their place. Would love to be able to fix this. :)

Comment: Maybe you can mark the equates as not being code somehow? Or, you could try to mark them local so they won't get written into the symbol table. Alternatively maybe you can set the base address so it's out of range of common equates.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution to the problem. Thankyou to all for their input as it allowed me to narrow the problem and go back to IAR tech support with a focussed query, and it was they that came up with the answer. The following shows a simple setup/program with some of the basics for assembler in IAR ARM Embedded workbench v7.30 which correctly single steps. The key line, that was not present before, is:

SECTION .text : CODE (2)

without which EW won't single step in the source, only the disassembly view. Adding it has made a BIG difference to it. Cheers @Jester and Ross Ridge.

```
RAM_START                   EQU              0x20000000
RAM_SIZE                    EQU              0x00020000
RAM_TOP                     EQU              RAM_START+RAM_SIZE

        PUBLIC  __iar_program_start      

        SECTION .noinit :DATA(2)
SRAM_data_buffer            DS8     16
        SECTION .intvec : CODE(2)
        DC32    RAM_TOP          ; Stack pointer start address top of SRAM
        DC32    __iar_program_start        ;jump to code start
        DC32    NMI_Vector
    /*Rest of the vectors in here*/ 
    SECTION .text : CODE (2)
        THUMB
__iar_program_start:  
/*Start of user code*/

code_end  B code_end
    DATA
    ALIGNROM 2
Constant                         DC8            1,2,'text'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in IAR 7.20.5.7624.

Solved selecting "Disassemble in Current processor mode" under the Disassembly menu entry.

I suppose it depends on the current mode of the CPU, if ARM or THUMB or THUMB2 mode.

BR,

Catosh.